# aspnetboilerplate .NET Core SignalR Integration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, nuget, signalr, aspnetboilerplate

I am using ABP's .NET Core template now, and have a need for real time notifications.

I read through ABP's documentation on SignalR, and wish to implement it, but when I tried to install the ABP's SignalR package, it complains that it is not compatible with .NET Core.

Is there something I am missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [normal asp.net version](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) of SignalR and the [asp.net core version](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR), make sure you're using the correct one.

### Edit

Seems the [ABP SignalR nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Abp.Web.SignalR) only supports the full framework, in which case you should probably reference the asp.net core version from above directly until they update their package to support core.

Answer (score 0):

SignalR 2 is built for .NET Framework, not for .NET Core. They are still working on SignalR for .NET Core.

https://vimeo.com/204078084

Comment: actually answer is "this feature is not available at the moment". I mentioned that in my first sentence. And the link is for further information.

Comment: I have to agree with @AlperEbicoglu here - this *does*, in fact, appear to be an answer to the question (even independently of the link).